# Fastest way to convert Python List with dictionaries to one dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have parsed large amount of data into list that contains dictionaries.

```
[{123123:[0.45, 0.4]},{2332:[0.1, 09]}]
```

I have close to 800,000 records in this list, and I want to get a dictionary out of it:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in dict_list:
    for k,v in i.iteritems():
        my_dict[k] = v
```

Is there a faster way to do this.

Comment: You are probably going to get better gains by changing the way that the data is parsed.  If you format the data correctly from the start then you won't need to do any of this.

Comment: On average how many keys are present in each dict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> dict_list = [{123123:[0.45, 0.4]},{2332:[0.1, 9]}]
>>> {key: item[key] for item in dict_list for key in item}
{123123: [0.45, 0.4], 2332: [0.1, 9]}
```

Since comprehensions are done with C code, it should be comparatively faster than iterating with Python and mutating the dictionary object.

Comment: Updating `my_dict` in OP's code should be even faster as it removes a Python for-loop.

Comment: I didn't know that there is also "dict comprehension". nice to know!! :)

Comment: Though note this doesn't account for duplicate keys. Or rather, it follows LIFO semantics; the value of the last encountered duplicate key will be the value at that key. If that's a possibility/problem, you'll need a more complex solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using update should be pretty efficient:

```
my_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    my_dict.update(d)
```

Some timings on your input:

```
In [13]: %%timeit
my_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    my_dict.update(d)
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 557 ns per loop

In [14]: timeit {key: item[key] for item in dict_list for key in item}
1000000 loops, best of 3: 597 ns per loop

In [15]: %%timeit                                         
my_dict = {}
for i in dict_list:
    for k,v in i.iteritems():
        my_dict[k] = v
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 664 ns per loop
In [16]: %%timeit
my_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    for k in d:
       my_dict[k] = d[k]
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 626 ns per loop
In [17]: timeit dict(reduce(operator.add, [dic.items() for dic in  dict_list]))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 µs per loop
```

One thing to note is if you have repeated keys then you will end up overwriting the value each time ending up with the last value you encounter for a particular  key.

Running the tests again with a list of 800000 dicts consisting of unique keys it shows the dict comprehension to be the fastest:

```
In [81]: dict_list = [{i:[1,2,3]} for i in xrange(800000)] 

In [82]: timeit {key: item[key] for item in dict_list for key in item} 
10 loops, best of 3: 165 ms per loop

In [83]: %%timeit                                                      
my_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    my_dict.update(d)
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 215 ms per loop

In [84]: %%timeit
my_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    for k in d:
       my_dict[k] = d[k]
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 198 ms per loop

In [85]: %%timeit                                                     
my_dict = {}
for i in dict_list:
    for k,v in i.iteritems():
        my_dict[k] = v
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 226 ms per loop
```

Just to verify the both produce the same output:

```
In [79]: my_dict = {}                                                 
for d in dict_list:
    my_dict.update(d)
   ....:    
In [115]: len(my_dict)
Out[115]: 2400000


In [80]: my_dict ==  {key: item[key] for item in dict_list for key in item}
Out[80]: True
```

Finally using three keys per dict, update wins again:

```
 In [108]: dict_list = [{i:[1000,2000,3000],i+800000:[1000,2000,3000],i+1700000:[1000,2000,3000]} for i in xrange(800000)]

In [109]: %%timeit
my_dict = {}
for i in dict_list:
    for k,v in i.iteritems():
        my_dict[k] = v
   .....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 468 ms per loop

In [110]: %%timeit
my_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    for k in d:              
       my_dict[k] = d[k]
   .....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 476 ms per loop

In [111]: timeit {key: item[key] for item in dict_list for key in item}
1 loops, best of 3: 448 ms per loop

In [112]: %%timeit                                                     
my_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    my_dict.update(d)
   .....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 328 ms per loop
```

So it seems having more keys helps to offset the cost of calling update so if you have one key as per your input then the dict comp should be faster, if you have multiple keys then update should be.

Comment: can you time your simple update for loop in combined with list comprehensions? ie. `timeit [my_dict.update(dic) for dic dict_list]` ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, `229 ms` on the large data set. Using a list comp in that manner would probably also be frowned upon ;)

Comment: Surprising to find it being slower than the "full" loop; I've assumed that a list comprehension would be faster, since python needn't check scope for ever iteration -- nice to know!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, using `dict.update` should be easier and faster:

```
my_dict = {}
for d in dict_list:
    my_dict.update(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` might still help you (although I messed up my previous answer):

```
import operator
dict(reduce(operator.add, [dic.items() for dic in dictlist]))
```

EDIT: thanks, @padraicCunningham, for testing my stuff (and showing it is not that great, at least for disjunct keys)